# How to generate a RNGCryptoServiceProvider-like number in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, random

Does anyone know of a way to generate a RNGCryptoServiceProvider-like random number in T-SQL without having to register any .NET Assemblies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT CHECKSUM(NEWID())` gives you a 32 signed integer based on GUIDs. You can use this as base: it's pretty much the best SQL way

You can use it to seed RAND (because RAND is the same for all rows in a single select.

```
SELECT RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
```

A signed 64 bit integer:

```
SELECT CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) as bigint) * CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) as bigint)
```

With some playing around you could cast and/or concatenate to get *binary("multiples of 4")* etc to build up a byte array... I've not used the RAND thingy though to emulate directly

Comment: This meets our needs as crypto randomness is not the goal; the real goal is to get large random numbers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to generate [cryptographycally secure random numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSPRNG) (like salts for hashing) then you should use the CLR functions. Checksum, guids and the like are not secure for crypto operations.

The easiest solution is to use a [CLR scalar function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189876.aspx) that invokes RNGCryptoServiceProvider.

Note that many of the SQL Server crpto functions like [EncryptByKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174361.aspx) are already salting the input using cryptographically secure generated salts (except for EncryptByKey on RC4 algorithm, that is broken in SQL).